# Исчезновение обратного слеша (\) при добавление строки в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема такая. Есть регулярное выражение с обратным слешем, которое заполняется в админке сайта. При добавлении в базу mysql, слеш исчезает, но так происходит только на удаленном хостинге, на локальном же все в порядке, слеш остается на месте. Фреймворк - kohana, использую query bilder

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $post = Validation::factory($_POST);
 print_r($post['config']);
// сюда получаем данные из формы
```

}

```
<p>
<!-- В ЭТО ПОЛЕ И ВВОДИМ  /^\/$/, НО В ИТОГЕ ИМЕЕМ  /^/$/  -->
    <?= Form::label('config', __('admin_widget_config_label')) ?>
    <?= Form::input('config', $widget['config'], array('size' => 100,'required' => 'required')) ?>

</p>
```

Comment: поправочка, \ исчезает еще до добавления в бд, то есть из $_POST

Comment: СОВЕТ: если мой ответ вас устроил, то примите его нажав на "птичку" слева от ответа под "голосовалкой", а то как я вижу вы не приняли не одного ответа на ваши предыдущие вопросы, и кроме меня вам никто не хочет отвечать на несложный вопрос именно из-за того, что у вас стоит под ником 0% принятых

Comment: в общем, вопрос открыт. Проверил на linux ngnix php 5.4, \\ не исчезает. Понять от чего все-таки зависит это исчезновение я так и не смог. Единственно, что связь версии php налицо, но вот каких-то настроек за это отвечающих я так и не нашел.

Comment: Ладно начнем все сначала, но приведите для начала что-нибудь из своего кода, например регулярку или строку, которая у вас обрабатывается не так, как хочется, а то гадать на кофейной гуще надоело немного :)

Comment: <!-- В ЭТО ПОЛЕ И ВВОДИМ  /^\/$/, НО В ИТОГЕ ИМЕЕМ  /^/$/  -->

Ну здесь все нормально - это escape-последовательность (еще примеры \\\, \\., \\*,\w и т.д. - здесь слеш служит только для того, что указать PHP как правильно трактовать след. за ним символ) для добавления символа "/" в строку, если написать без обратного слеша, то получим неверное рег. выражение "/^/". Так что ваша проблема в этом случае натграна недостаточным знанием синтаксиса рег. выражений применительно к PHP

Ну и интересно конечно узнать решение! 2 день мозги сушу над этим вопросом :)))

Comment: Вы читали дополнение к вопросу? "поправочка, \ исчезает еще до добавления в бд, то есть из $_POST" Регулярные выражения вообще не причем. Как видно из кода, проверка на рег. выражения  вообще нигде не происходит. Слеш исчезал прямо после отправки формы через post. Развернуты ответ здесь не дам, но я по этому поводу статью накалякал, если интересно, вот ссылка http://webnotes.by/docs/php/kohana/264

Comment: Мда, а я то думал речь совсем о другом, а тут оказывается AND (даже и не знал, что это альтернатива && в PHP) виноват. Кстати прикольный дизайн у вашего сайта! Сами делали или это готовое решение? Ну не обойдусь и без совета: logo не совсем натурально себя ведет при наведении на некоторые области, также если страница с малым количеством контента footer не прижат к низу, например здесь http://webnotes.by/docs/sql . Сорри за оффтоп.

Comment: ну дизайна там нет, там css фрэймворк tw-bootstrap, таким образом на верстку у меня ушло часа два, нет ни времени ни особого желания делать некий уникальный дизайн, все что я сделал это логотип. Футер я как-нить прижму как руки дойдут

Answer (score 1):

А после обработки регуляркой строка содержит этот слеш?? Попробуйте экранировать в регулярке таким способом:

```
'/\\\\/'
```

Выдержка из книги по PHP:

Как видите, синтаксис записи строк в РНР требует, чтобы все обратные слэши 
в программе были удвоены. Поэтому мы получаем весьма неказистую
конструкцию — '/path\\/to\\/file/i'. Проблема в том, что символы-ограничители
совпадают с символами, которые мы ищем. 
Специально для того чтобы упростить запись, язык PCRE поддерживает
использование альтернативных ограничителей. В их роли может выступать буквально все, что 
угодно. Например, следующие регулярные выражения означают одно и то же: 
// Можно использовать любые одинаковые символы как ограничители...

```
'/path\\/to\\/file/i' 
'#path/to/file#i' 
'"path/to/file"i' 
//А можно — парные скобки
'{path/to/file}i' 
'[path/to/file]i'
'(path/to/file)i'
```

Последние три примера особенно интересны: как видите, если в качестве
начального ограничителя выступает скобка, то финальный символ должен быть равен парной 
ей скобке. 
Польза от парных скобок огромна. Дело в том, что при их использовании скобки, 
встречающиеся внутри выражений, уже не нужно экранировать обратным слэшем: 
анализатор PCRE самостоятельно "считает" вложенность скобок и не поднимает 
ложной тревоги. Например, следующее выражение корректно: 
echo preg_replace (' [ (/file) [0-9]+]i\ '$1\ "/filel23.txt") ; 
Хотя квадратные скобки в регулярных выражениях — это спецсимволы,
обозначающие "альтернативу символов", нам не приходится ставить перед ними обратный 
слэш, несмотря на то, что они совпадают с ограничителями.

Comment: magic_quotes_gpc = 1 – Символы одиночные (‘) и двойные кавычки («), обратный слеш (), байт NULL в данные, получаемых из массивов $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, автоматически экранируются интерпретатором PHP. Перед каждым таким символом добавляется обратный слеш.

Возможно поэтому не локальном серве все нормально. Проверьте с помощью следующей ф-и включена эта опция или нет (если вернет 1, то да, 0 - нет):

     get_magic_quotes_gpc ()

Comment: get_magic_quotes_gpc  отключен

Comment: если написать /^\\\/$/ вместо /^\/$/, то все ок, в итоге имеем /^\/$/, но все-таки хотелось бы понять почему это / исчезает

Comment: В вашей регулярке / воспринимается как символ конца выражения, тоесть /^\/$/ воспринимается как /^\/, а не так как вы хотите. Можно попробовать использовать например # вместо / ( #^\/$# ). Подробности добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо, только вот не ясно почему на локальном сервере все ок, а проблема только на удаленном хостинге

Comment: Скорее всего из-за того, что ваш локальый сервер на Винде, а удаленный естественно на Линуксе, а как известно Виндовс воспринимает \ и / за один символ в путях, а для Линукса это разные символы. Вот из-за этих особенностей в ОС у вас скорее всего и получается разное поведение! Ну а так еще, конечно, могут быть разные настройки у Apache, отвечающие за обработку спецсимволов.

Comment: я тут потестил и пришел к выводу. Слеш исчезает уже в $_POST придя из формы, другими словами, что означает \\. Экранирование! Вот он и занимается своими обязанностями. Получается \\ экранирует \/ и выполнив свое исчезает, вот и все. Дело не в регулярных выражениях, ведь \\ исчезает еще в посте. А на локале стоит php 5.4 а в нем автоматическое эеранирование исключено. Может в этом дело?

Comment: Ну вы и дотошный :))) Ну да может, цитата из мануала по ПХП о автоматической вставке экранирующих слешей:

    Данная возможность была помечена УСТАРЕВШЕЙ начиная с версии PHP 5.3.0 и   была УДАЛЕНА в версии PHP 5.4.0.

Правда, \ не экранирует /, а исчезает по той причине, что сам должен быть экранирован ( \\\\ ). Даже здесь на сайте, чтобы втавить двойной слеш в пред. предложении, мне приходится писать 4 штуки :)) А одиночный как раз-таки не исчезает! :) одиночный - \ ; двойной - \\ ; тройной - \\\ ; четыре - \\\\ ; пять - \\\\\ дальше продолжать не буду)))